# in ms graph api not able to filter on basis of sender information

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I want to fetch all emails who are sent by xyz@example.com to my email but when I apply the filter it does not return me emails, it return empty array

---

I followed this ms explorer link as guidance and found url to be used to filter according to sender information https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

I am trying to fetch with this url and filter option

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myemail@example.com/messages?$filter=(from/emailAddress/address) eq 'xyz@example.com'
```

but this return empty result even I have full permissions and I saw ms graph explorer and api documentation they have mentioned this url to fetch by sender information/email

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=(from/emailAddress/address) eq '{user-mail}'
```

Comment: Similar request with the filter works fine for me. Did you try the requests from Graph Explorer or from some php code?

Comment: @user2250152 is this url request works fine with you ? GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myemail@example.com/messages?$filter=(from/emailAddress/address) eq 'xyz@example.com'  ? or by using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter ? please confirm

Comment: Both requests `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=(from/emailAddress/address) eq '{user-mail}'` and `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/mymail@tenant.com/messages?$filter=(from/emailAddress/address) eq '{user-mail}'` work fine but I'm trying them from Graph Explorer, not from PHP